# syntax error in spark when setting sqlcontext

Tags: apache-spark

I get a syntax error when trying to set a variable to the `sqlcontext.table`.

```
parsed_log_files.toDF().registerTempTable("log_data")
val sc = sqlContext.table("log_data")
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax File "",
>   line 2 val sc = sqlContext.table("log_data")

Comment: Can you show the complete relevant program/class/file?

Comment: adding to hage's request, what are you trying to do also would help.